# In the case of two equally charged particles, is the electric field between them incompressible?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

When approach two electrons (or two protons or ...), the electric fields do not merge and stay isolated from each other.

[image: here are two positiv charged particles]

Which I borrowed from [here](http://cnx.org/content/m42331/latest/).

Is it right to conclude that in the case of equaly charged particles the two fields are incompressible?

Comment: What do you mean "the electric fields do not merge"? You are aware the the field lines are just *one* way of visualizing vector fields, right?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a two charge configuration like this one, *every* point in space is going to have an electric field vector with contribution from both the charges. There is only one electric field, and it wouldn't make sense to talk about the two electric fields as different entities (and consequentially, about ideas like 'compressibility'). You must remember that field lines are just a tool we use to represent electric fields conveniently, and that these lines have no real life significance.

Comment: When you put hands together, would you say that this as one body ore are this two bodies? In the case of two equal charges there is a boundary surface with electric potential equal to zero. do we have two electric fields or is this one field? I tend to say, there are still two fields.